# How to get the onmousemove functions final value into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jsp

i am doing a jsp page which record the moment of mouse in that page. i had the code to record the moment but i dont know how to get the final value of total moments to a variable?

```
<div onmousemove="myMoveFunction()">
  <p>onmousemove: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over and leave me!</span></p>
</div>


<script>
var x = 0;

var y = 0;

var z = 0;


function myMoveFunction()
 {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z+=1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Umm... doesn't `z` contain the "final value"?

Answer (score 1):

You must to specify your handler before you use it.

```
<script>
var x = 0;

var y = 0;

var z = 0;

function myMoveFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z += 1;
}
</script>

<div onmousemove="myMoveFunction()">
  <p>onmousemove:
    <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over and leave me!</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get X and Y coords, note that you cannot get Z coords. To get Z coords, your computer would need to be 3-D, which is not possible. :) W3 Schools has good documentation of getting X and Y coordinates. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp and this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_clientxy

I see that your function is not defined before the HTML uses it, that could be the problem.